# NSCFArray leak in the NSMutablearray allocation

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I am getting the leak at this allocation

```
filteredListContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[showList count]];
```

CODE:

```
-(void)reloadTable
{
    EventListAppDelegate *appDelegate;
    UIApplication app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    appDelegate = (EventListAppDelegate *)[app delegate];

    contactList = [appDelegate getAllContactsList];
    inviteeList = [appDelegate getInviteeListForEvent:event.primaryKey];

    if (isInvited == YES)
    {
        showList = [appDelegate getInviteeListForEvent:event.primaryKey];
    }
    else
    {
        showList = [appDelegate getAllContactsList];
    }

    filteredListContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:
                           [showList count]];

    [filteredListContent addObjectsFromArray: showList];

    [self organizeContactItemsIntoIndexes];
    self.title = [event.name capitalizedString];

    [self getToolbar];        
    [theTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; 

    ContactDTO *currentElement;
    NSRange range;

    for (currentElement in showList)
    {
        range = [currentElement.lastName rangeOfString:searchText
                                         options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if(range.location == 0)
        {
            [filteredListContent addObject:currentElement];
        }
    }

    [self organizeContactItemsIntoIndexes];
    [theTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [filteredListContent release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code will allocate a new instance of `filteredListContent` every time `reloadTable` is called, which will usually happen several times during the lifetime of your application. This causes a leak because the old instances are not released.

The best (and easiest) way to fix it would be to make `filteredListContent` a `retain` property:

> **in your class header:**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * filteredListContent;
```

> **in your reloadTable method:**

```
self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[showList count]];
```

Note the use of `self.` in the second code snippet. That syntax informs Cocoa that it should use the property accessor to set the value of `filteredListContent`, which will then send the appropriate `retain` and `release` messages for you.

Comment: Note that there's no need to use `-arrayWithCapacity:`, using `-array` will work exactly the same way without performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

You've posted three nearly-identical questions pertaining to memory leaks.  It might be helpful for you to read through [Apple's Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).